# need to replace a pattern in a file with spaces

Tags: sed, grep

I have a file which contains numeric values with hypens / spaces in between; need to replace it with spaces ex: 333-44-5555 / 333 44 5555

```
grep '[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{4\}'
grep '[0-9]\{3\} [0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{4\}'  ==> fetches me with all cases;
```

but how to replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do (with a sed that has a `-E` option to enable EREs, e.g. GNU sed and OSX/BSD sed)?

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\1 \2 \3/g'
```

e.g.:

```
$ echo '333-44-5555' | sed -E 's/([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\1 \2 \3/g'
333 44 5555
```

I'm assuming you have other `-`s in your text that you DON"T want transformed to spaces otherwise a simple `tr '-' ' ' < file` is all you'd need.

---

EDIT per your comment below it sounds like this is what you actually want:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{3}[- ][0-9]{2}[- ][0-9]{4}/ /g'
```

Comment: thanks . But I need to replace the whole 333-44-5555 to spaces

Comment: echo '333-44-5555' | sed -E 's/([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/ /g'

Comment: The above one will work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -i.bak 's/-/ /' filename
```

will replace your '-' by a real space in the whole file keeping a backup of original file.

to replace the whole string :

```
sed  -i .bak 's/[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{4\}/ /'
```

Comment: need to replace the whole string with spaces; not only -

Answer (score -1):

This is what I use. 
Keeps original file and makes newfile with you results.

```
sed 's/-/ /g' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Try it on a copy first just to see.